# Not getting response while ajax call in jQuery Data table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I tried ajax call in separate page it's working fine but through jQuery data table I'm not getting response.

API is in AWS. I tried though API end point with key.

Problem is while trying ajax request in jQuery data table the request payload not send properly it shows an encryption data and also not return any response.

**Sample code as given below:**

var dataListNew = { "fromDate": "2021-01-01", "toDate": "2021-01-14"};

```
$('#co-table').DataTable({          
        //"scrollY": "400px",
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
         buttons: [
                    {
                        extend:    'copyHtml5',
                        text:      '<i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'Copy'
                    },
                    {
                        extend:    'excelHtml5',
                        text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'Excel'
                    },
                    {
                        extend:    'csvHtml5',
                        text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'CSV'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        orientation: 'landscape',
                        //pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                        text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'PDF'
                    },
                    {
                        extend:    'print',
                        text:      '<i class="fa fa-print"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'Print'
                    }
                ],                  
                            
        "ajax": {
             url         : applicationApiEndPoint+page,
             method      : "POST",
             dataType    : "json",
             data        : JSON.stringify(dataListNew)
             headers    : {
                    "authorizationToken":   authorizationToken,
                    "Cache-Control"     :   "no-cache, no-store",
                    "Content-Type"      :   "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "x-api-key"         :   applicationApiKey,
                    "sciappID"          :   appID,
                    "sciappuserID"      :   userID
            }
        },
        
        "columns": [
            { "data": "PROCESSDATE" },
            { "data": "MODELNAME" },
            { "data": "MODELSTARTTIME", 
                render: function (data, type, row)
                {....
```

[Request Payload][it look like fully encrypted]

Comment: You mentioned that you are having an error - what is the error? Can you [edit] your question?

Comment: I mentioned exact problem please check.

Comment: _request payload not send properly_ - You don't show us where the `dataListNew` data comes from. From the original version of the question, look at this: `0={&1="&2=f&3=r&4=o&5=m&6=D&7=a&...`, This is not encrypted data. It is HTML form data, which has been [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) from what looks like an array of characters. If you URL-decode it you can see the text in the data: `{"fromDate":"2021-01-01","toDate":"2021-01-15"...`. I don't know how you managed to do this - but I would start by taking a closer look at `data : JSON.stringify(dataListNew)`.

Comment: yes only i send fromDate and toDate json object in dataListNew variable..i tried postman as well its working fine but when try in jquery datatable its send request payload as url encode. eg: look below request payload                                               var dataListNew = { "fromDate": "2019-03-01", "toDate": "2019-03-01"};

Comment: Understood - but as I mentioned, you don't show us where that `dataListNew` data comes from.

Comment: i just hardcode the request

Comment: its not come from html form...I just hardcode the dataListNew in jquery and pass the dataListNew to jquery datatable ajax

Answer (score 1):

You have the following variable containing the object you want to send to the server in your request:

```js
var dataListNew = { "fromDate": "2021-01-01", "toDate": "2021-01-14"};
```

In your DataTables ajax call you are stringifying this variable:

```js
data: JSON.stringify(dataListNew), // note you have a missing comma in your version
```

But `JSON.stringify` will cause the JSON object to be converted to a string - and then the `data` option will try to interpret that string as follows:

> *When data is passed as a string it should already be encoded using the correct encoding for contentType, which by default is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.*

See the [jQuery ajax documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for details.

In your case, the string is not encoded correctly for that to work. Instead, you will get the URL-encoded data you are seeing:

```
0=%7B&1=%22&2=f&3=r&4=o&5=m&6=D&7=a&8=t&9=e&10=%22&11...
```

Instead, just pass the JSON object to the ajax `data` option:

```js
data: dataListNew,
```

Now, the request payload will be constructed as per the following documentation guidelines:

> *When data is an object, jQuery generates the data string from the object's key/value pairs...*

Now the payload looks like this in the request body:

```
fromDate=2021-01-01&toDate=2021-01-14
```

And therefore your server-side PHP logic should be able to read the request body in the usual way.

Comment: The question you asked was about the request payload: _"the request payload not send properly"_. Now you are asking a completely different question.

Comment: Ok..why i'm not getting response from server side.

Comment: You can ask your question (about your CORS problem) _by creating a new, separate question_. In other words, don't try to combine it into this existing question. Having said that, there are many, many CORS questions already on Stack Overflow - so please remember to research those answers first, before posting a new question.

Comment: Can you see my new question...title is...Getting CORS origin error while ajax call in jQuery Data table