# Getting CORS origin error while ajax call in jQuery Data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, aws-lambda, datatables

**Here I put my code:**

```
var dataList = {    
    "fromDate": "2021-01-01",
    "toDate": "2021-01-16"
};

var dataListNew = JSON.stringify(dataList);


$('#co-table').DataTable({  
        //"scrollY": "400px",
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
         buttons: [
                    {
                        extend:    'copyHtml5',
                        text:      '<i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'Copy'
                    },
                    {
                        extend:    'excelHtml5',
                        text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'Excel'
                    },
                    {
                        extend:    'csvHtml5',
                        text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'CSV'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        orientation: 'landscape',
                        //pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                        text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'PDF'
                    },
                    {
                        extend:    'print',
                        text:      '<i class="fa fa-print"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'Print'
                    }
                ],                  
                            
        "ajax": {
             url         : "https://XXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XYXYX/YYY",
             method      : "POST",
             dataType    : "json",
             contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             data        : dataListNew,
             headers    : {
                    "authorizationToken" :  authorizationToken,
                    "Cache-Control"      :  "no-cache, no-store",
                    "Content-Type"       :  "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "x-api-key"          :  applicationApiKey,
                    "sciappID"           :  appID,
                    "sciappuserID"       :  userID
            }
        },
        
        "columns": [
            { "data": "PROCESSDATE" },
            { "data": "MODELNAME" },
            { "data": "MODELSTARTTIME", 
                render: function (data, type, row)
                {
                    if (data == null)
                    {
                        return '';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return moment(row.MODELSTARTTIME).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                    }
                }               
            },
            { "data": "MODELEXECUTIONSTATUS" },
            { "data": "MODELENDTIME", 
                render: function (data, type, row)
                {
                    if (data == null)
                    {
                        return '';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return moment(row.MODELENDTIME).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                    }
                }                               
            },
            
            { 
                "data": "RECORDCOUNT",
                "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0 )
            },
            { 
                "data": "EXPORTEDCOUNT",
                "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0 ) 
            },
            { 
                "data": "APPLIEDDECILE",
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                            return data == 'N' ? '<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>';
                        }
            },
            { 
                "data": "ACTUALRECORDCOUNT",
                "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0 )
            },
            // { "data": "IS_SCHEMA_VALIDATED" },
            { "data": "PROCESS_TYPE" }
        ]       
    });
```

**Regarding CORS origin error getting in console:**

> (index):1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xyxyxy.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/xxxx' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**Request payload shows encoded:**
0=%7B&1=%22&2=f&3=r&4=o&5=m&6=D&7=a&8=t&9=e&10=%22&11=%3A&12=%22&13=2&14=0&15=2&16=1&17=-&18=0&19=1&20=-&21=0&22=1&23=%22&24=%2C&25=%22&26=t&27=o&28=D&29=a&30=t&31=e&32=%22&33=%3A&34=%22&35=2&36=0&37=2&38=1&39=-&40=0&41=1&42=-&43=1&44=6&45=%22&46=%2C&47=%22&48=p&49=r&50=o&51=c&52=e&53=s&54=s&55=T&56=y&57=p&58=e&59=%22&60=%3A&61=%22&62=%22&63=%2C&64=%22&65=m&66=o&67=d&68=e&69=l&70=N&71=a&72=m&73=e&74=%22&75=%3A&76=%22&77=%22&78=%2C&79=%22&80=s&81=e&82=a&83=r&84=c&85=h&86=L&87=o&88=g&89=%22&90=%3A&91=%22&92=%7B&93=%5C&94=%22&95=a&96=p&97=p&98=N&99=a&100=m&101=e&102=%5C&103=%22&104=%3A&105=%5C&106=%22&107=c&108=o&109=x&110=-&111=m&112=o&113=d&114=e&115=l&116=-&117=f&118=a&119=c&120=t&121=o&122=r&123=y&124=-&125=d&126=e&127=v&128=e&129=l&130=o&131=p&132=m&133=e&134=n&135=t&136=%5C&137=%22&138=%2C&139=%5C&140=%22&141=a&142=p&143=p&144=P&145=a&146=g&147=e&148=%5C&149=%22&150=%3A&151=%5C&152=%22&153=m&154=o&155=d&156=e&157=l&158=-&159=m&160=o&161=d&162=e&163=l&164=%5C&165=%22&166=%2C&167=%5C&168=%22&169=a&170=p&171=p&172=I&173=D&174=%5C&175=%22&176=%3A&177=%5C&178=%22&179=%5C&180=%22&181=%2C&182=%5C&183=%22&184=a&185=u&186=t&187=h&188=T&189=y&190=p&191=e&192=%5C&193=%22&194=%3A&195=%5C&196=%22&197=g&198=o&199=o&200=g&201=l&202=e&203=%5C&204=%22&205=%2C&206=%5C&207=%22&208=u&209=s&210=e&211=r&212=E&213=m&214=a&215=i&216=l&217=%5C&218=%22&219=%3A&220=%5C&221=%22&222=v&223=i&224=m&225=a&226=l&227=r&228=a&229=j&230=%40&231=s&232=c&233=i&234=e&235=r&236=a&237=.&238=c&239=o&240=m&241=%5C&242=%22&243=%2C&244=%5C&245=%22&246=u&247=s&248=e&249=r&250=I&251=D&252=%5C&253=%22&254=%3A&255=%5C&256=%22&257=1&258=0&259=6&260=3&261=6&262=6&263=1&264=1&265=1&266=4&267=7&268=3&269=1&270=2&271=6&272=3&273=3&274=5&275=6&276=0&277=7&278=%5C&279=%22&280=%2C&281=%5C&282=%22&283=u&284=s&285=e&286=r&287=I&288=P&289=%5C&290=%22&291=%3A&292=%5C&293=%22&294=%5C&295=%22&296=%7D&297=%22&298=%7D

Comment: I described how to fix the _"Request payload shows encoded"_ problem in my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65742066/not-getting-response-while-ajax-call-in-jquery-data-table). You may want to update this new question to reflect that, so that this question only focuses on the CORS problem.

Comment: Did you research existing CORS questions and answer on Stack Overflow?